# I'm trying to create a validation for my form

Tags: javascript, html, validation

My goal is to create a text for a username where a user would enter text but if the words are less than five letters, then the paragraph underneath would alert them that their username is less than five letters. I am using an event handler to go about this, something which I am still learning to workaround, so I would like to know what I am doing wrong. I also added fallback codes for older browsers.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="text1"
  /><p id="response"></p>
</form>

function input(e, minlength) {
  var target1 = e.target || e.srcElement; //element which the event is working on
  var paragraph1 = target.nextSibling;

  if (!e) {
    e = window.event;
  }
  
  
  if (target1.value.length < minlength) {
    paragraph1.textContent =
      "Your username should be" + minlength + "letters and above";
  }
}

var input1 = document.getElementById("text1");
if (input1.addEventListener) {
  input1.addEventListener(
    "blur",
    function (e) {
      input(e, 5);
    },
    false
  );
}

else{
  input1.attachEvent(
    "onblur",
    function (e) {
      input(e, 5);
    },
    false
  );
}
```

Comment: _"I also added fallback codes for older browsers."_ - regarding addEventListener , that should really not be necessary - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#browser_compatibility

Comment: _"so i would like to know what I am doing wrong"_ - have you not checked your browser console? I get an error message, saying `target` is not defined, for `var paragraph1 = target.nextSibling;` You meant `target1` there.

Comment: @CBroe I feel so stupid right now :) , it's working now, thanks a lot.

Comment: What helps me solve issues in JavaScript was learning to [use the debugger built into your browser](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp) to set a breakpoint in that function. Then step through it line by line to see when it throws. I use this **all the friggen' time**. It's definitely a necessary life skill for anyone who works with JavaScript.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your title should be a clear, specific question and not just a statement of your overall goal.

Comment: @isherwoods Sorry i'm still working my way around the site, but thanks for the link

Comment: @Liquorice ... how about using at first place everything [built in form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#using_built-in_form_validation) offers/covers? In addition read about [constraint validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Constraint_validation).

Answer (score 1):

This code should do it! It's nothing fancy, but you can build on it pretty easily.

```js
// Select the input and paragraph elements
const inputElement = document.getElementById('text1');
const paragraphElement = document.getElementById('response');

// Add an event listener to the input element
inputElement.addEventListener('input', function() {
  // Get the value of the input
  const inputValue = inputElement.value;

  // Check the length of the input value
  if (inputValue.length < 5) {
    paragraphElement.textContent = 'Input is less than 5 characters';
  } else {
    paragraphElement.textContent = 'Input is 5 characters or more';
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="text1"
  /><p id="response"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should correct this line because of this line paragraph1 is not get properly  you should use nextElementSibling to get paragraph1

```
 var paragraph1 = target.nextSibling;
```

you should correct above line to

```
var paragraph1 = target1.nextElementSibling;
```